# Function that's a metric on one space but not another?

Tags: functions, metric-spaces

Is there a function which makes sense on two sets and is a metric on one but not the other? I can't seem to come up with an example or a proof a metric on one set implies it is on every other one it can be defined.

Thanks

Comment: By definition, a function cannot be defined on two different sets. Maybe if you were to write down an example you have in mind, one can figure out what exactly you want to know.

Comment: That's true, but you could have sets $A,B,C$ with $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$ and then if you have the function from $C$, you can restrict it to  $A$ and $B$ and that's what I meant by makes sense on two sets $A$ and $B$. The thing that got me thinking was $d(x,y) = \frac{1}{1+n}$ where n is the index where the decimal expansion of $x$ and $y$ differ for the first time defined on irrationals. I wasn't sure if this could be extended to reals, and still be a metric. After a bit of thought, I think it can (maybe). But then it got me wondering if this is always the case or not

Comment: How about this: $A = \mathbb{R}$, $B = \{a,b\}$, $C = A \cup B = \mathbb{R} \cup \{a,b\}$. Define $d : C \times C \to [0,\infty)$ as follows. If $x \in A$ and $y \in A$ define $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. For all other $(x,y) \in C \times C$, define $d(x,y)=0$. So the restriction of $d$ to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is the usual metric, whereas the restriction of $d$ to $C \times C$ has constant value $0$ which is not a metric. This example, combined with your comment, leads me to believe that perhaps you did not quite ask the question that you wanted to ask.

Comment: @LeeMosher did you mean the restriction of $d$ to $B \times B$ has constant value 0? But yeah thats the sort of counter example I was looking for. Thankyou

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such issues are encountered when one attempts to [glue metric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803196/) together, even when the parts to be glued are disjoint. For example, let $A$ be the interval $[0,1]$ with the standard metric $d_A(x,y)=|x-y|$, and $B=[2,3]$  with the metric $d_B(x,y) = 10|x-y|$. We could try to put these together into one space $X=[0,1]\cup [2,3] $, extending the metric as $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ when $x\in A$, $y\in B$ or vice versa. The resulting function $d:X\times X\to \mathbb R$ is not a metric because, e.g., $d(2,3)>d(1,2)+d(1,3)$. The restrictions of $d$ to $A\times A$ and $B\times B$ are metrics, however.